# hardware mic control

Tags: java, javasound

How can I control the mic on-off function using java code? I need to control the time for which mic is on.
I tried using the following code in java:

```
final AudioFormat format = getFormat();//getformat() has the audio format
    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
    final TargetDataLine line   = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);

    line.open(format);                         //open mic for input
line.start();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1048576];
OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();//output the audio to buffer
boolean running = true;

    try {
        while (running) {
        int count = line.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        running=false;
            if (count > 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, count);               
            }
        }
            out.close();                             

    } catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Error");
        System.err.println("I/O problems: " + e);
        System.exit(-1);
          }
```

But this basically depends on the the size of buffer. And the **while** loop can input audio for 30secs per pass.
I need to take the sample inputs for just 10secs.
any help?? thanks.:)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Also, please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to control the duration of the miking via the size of the buffer. I'm pretty sure this isn't common practice. Usually one uses a buffer that is a fraction of a second in size (to keep latency low), and iterates through it repeatedly. To control the duration of an open-ended read or playback operation, it is more usual to change the value of the "running" boolean.

Thus, from outside of the loop, code updates the "running" boolean, and when the loop notices that there has been a request to stop, the read loop ends.

I'm not up on specifics as to how one gets permission to turn on a mike or not. I know the java sound tutorials talk about it.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/capturing.html

In their example, they use a boolean "stopped" to control when to end the recording loop.

Comment: got it.. thanks..:) Suppose I take in stream of data through mic in a smaller buffer. I need to to process that data to find frequencies. But when I am processing the data, is there a way that mic still remains on and keeps on receiving another set of data??

Comment: If the processing is quick you might be able to do it within your while loop. Or you can direct the output to another line and thread where the analysis occurs concurrently. Usually, the above code would be in its own thread so as not to block other activity.

Comment: pretty long processing due to FFT.. ll do 2nd option.. thanks..:)